# How can you extract a nested JSON value?

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

Can someone with experience using JSON and Access together tell me what I'm doing wrong with this code?  I'm trying to parse a JSON file and there's one nested data item that I can't seem to extract.  The problem portion of the JSON data is as follows:

```
credits":{
"director":[{"displayName":"Bradley Cooper","firstName":"Bradley","lastName":"Cooper","bio":""}],
"cast":["Bradley Cooper"," Lady Gaga"," Andrew Dice Clay"," Dave Chappelle"," Sam Elliott"]
}
```

I can extract the cast names with no problem, but I can't retrieve the "displayname" for the director.  The nested "{}" brackets inside the "director" item are throwing me off.  Here's my code:

```
 Sub JSON_prob_demo()

    Dim url As String, data As String
    Dim xml As Object, JSON As Object, colObj As Object, colobj2 As Object, colObj3 As Object, item As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant, varX As Variant

    url = "https://www.tiff.net/data/films/a-star-is-born.json"

    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        data = .responseText
    End With


    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data)

    Set colObj = JSON("credits")
    For Each c1 In colObj("cast")
        Debug.Print c1
    Next

    Debug.Print "Director:"
    Set colobj2 = colObj("director")
    For Each c1 In colobj2
        Debug.Print c1("displayname")
    Next

End Sub
```

I've been able to extract the names of the four director fields, but I simply cannot access their values.  What's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
Sub getHTTP()

    Dim Url As String, data As String
    Dim xml As Object, JSON As Object, colObj, item


    Url = "https://www.tiff.net/data/films/a-star-is-born.json"

    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        data = .responseText
    End With


    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data)
    Set colObj = JSON("credits")("director")



    For Each item In colObj

      For j = 0 To item.Count - 1
              Debug.Print item.Items()(j)
         Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Print**

Note: Item is dictionary object so used `Debug.Print item.Items()(j)` to retrieve key values.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  I'm glad that I knew when to throw in the towel, or I would have wasted all of this time getting nowhere.  Is there any good online documentation on the intricacies of parsing JSON data that you know of?

Comment: You don't need to go through documentation but it easy once you play with few json data [here](http://jsonpathfinder.com/)